# ssh-agent does not autostart from .bashrc after update to 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, autostart, ssh-agent

I have Ubuntu with XFCE for several years. When it was 16.04 I configured the autostart of `ssh-agent` in my `.bashrc` as follows:

```
# Set up ssh-agent
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_github
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable
if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

The above code was taken from [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login).

Recently I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and the above snippet stopped working. I have to manually type `start_agent` in my command line now.

Any clues how to make it autostart on login again?